# There's already data in [SheetName][PivotTableName]". Do you want to replace it?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an Excel 2016 template with pivot tables, pivot charts, and a dashboard where I am dynamically updating data depending on various selections and filters. Whenever I open up a new version of the report (Excel file) I get the following message for each chart:

> There's already data in [SheetName][PivotTableName]". Do you want to replace it?

I have browsed the internet and I have found 2 different solutions that have not worked.

1. I tried to create a Macro that disabled messages and then
   refreshed all data. I used the following bit of VBA code to disables messages but it did not work as expected:

   ```
   Applictaion.DisplayAlerts = false
   ```
2. I went into the advanced options of Excel I tried to disable
   the setting for "Alert before overwriting cells". This did not solve
   my issues and I asked a coworker to try on his machine as well and
   he too got the same message.

Does anyone know how to disable this message from popping up?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

In addition for your first solution:

1. Use before the code that pop's the warning:

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

2. After the code is finished, enable the alrert mode again:

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Answer (score 0):

' There are anothers events that can be Disabled before de code and Enabled after the code to improve the performance of the vba.

' 1. Before the code that pop's the warning, disable all:

```
Sub DisableAll()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="your password"
    Next
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

' 2. After the code is finished, enable all events, alerts and protected sheets again:

```
Sub EnableAll()

    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Worksheet.Protect Password:="your password", DrawingObjects:=True, contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    Next
    Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```